# please suggest me an API or suggestion to list facilities around an piece of land

Tags: android, api, scraping

I am building an android app for property listings for farmlands and vacant lands, it should include a feature to extract list of nearby facilities like, roads, highways, water-bodies, factories, markets, storage facilities, airports, hospitals, residential areas, schools, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/) which is an Open Source Geographic Information System. Currently it available for Windows, Mac & Linux but Android support is "Coming Soon"